# Run another function after loading the Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

```
$(document).on('change', '#id_edit_profile_photo', e => {
    uploadPhoto(avatarElem, previewPPContainer, avatarUploadElem)
});


function uploadPhoto(elem, preview, uploadElem) {
    elem.addClass('d-none');
    preview.removeClass('d-none');

    preview.find('img').attr('src', '');

    let blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(uploadElem.files[0]);
    preview.find('img').attr('src', blobUrl);
    // call this fuunction after completing the above task
    ImageLoaded();
}

function ImageLoaded() {
    _IMAGE_WIDTH = $("#drag-image").width();
    _IMAGE_HEIGHT = $("#drag-image").height();
    _IMAGE_LOADED = 1;  
    alert('Image Loaded');
}
```

The `uploadPhoto` function runs when value of the file input tag `#id_edit_profile_photo` changes. Inside the `uploadPhoto` blobUrl variable stores the url of the loaded file. The url is then set to an img tag. How do I allow the `ImageLoaded` function to run only after the img tag has loaded the image.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `<img>` elements have their own `load` event you can listen to. That will let you know whenever an image has finished loading.

Comment: Did you try `preview.find('img').load(function() { ImageLoaded(); });`? Agree with @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it worked, thank you so much

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky `.load()` is deprecated as a shortcut for `on('load'..`